# Domain name in URL as variable

Tags: mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file has the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php?domain=$1 [L]
```

I'm trying to get domain names as variables from URLs like:

hxxp://www.example.com/www.domain.name or

hxxp://www.example.com/subdomain.domain.name or

hxxp://www.example.com/domain.name

but with $_GET['domain'] my variable is always 'index.php' and not the domain names.

With hxxp://www.example.com/domain/www.domain.name and .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^domain/?(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

everything is OK, but I would like to remove the 'domain/' part from the URLs.

I've searched for this, but couldn't find anything. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?domain=$1 [L]
```

in this case $1 will be:

```
http://site/www.example.com        $1 = www.example.com
http://site/www.example.com/xyz    $1 = www.example.com/xyz
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but redirects as a non search engine friendly URL. I would like to leave the URLs as in my example.

Comment: k, if you remove the [R=302] it will do an internal redirect, preserving the neat url (edited above)

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/.](\.[^/]+)+$ index.php?domain=$0 [L]
```

This will rewrite any request with a URL path that contains at least one dot (`foo.bar`, `foo.bar.baz`, etc.) to your *index.php*.

Comment: Thank you! The code you wrote did not work for me (404 Not Found error for a domain name entered after the forward slash). I'm pretty new to mod_rewrite, but I modified the last line to RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L] and this works, although I really do not know what it does.