# htaccess rewrite url using last parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a query on htaccess i need to rewrite a url like below example

```
www.example.com/parameater1/parameater2/parameater3/name=xyz
```

i need something like below

```
www.xyz.example.com/parameater1/parameater2/parameater3
```

i tried the below code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.example\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.example.co.uk/test/$1/$2/$3?user=%1" [P]
```

but unable to resolve using the above code

Comment: can you check this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039801/domain-name-in-url-as-variable` if it could help you.

Comment: Which one you want as your desired result `www.example.com/parameater1/parameater2/parameater3/name=xyz` or `www.xyz.example.com/parameater1/parameater2/parameater3`

Comment: www.example.com/parameater1/parameater2/parameater3/name=xyz        this url need to be like www.xyz.example.com/parameater1/parameater2/parameater3

Answer (score 1):

Not best, but should work.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*)/name=(.*)$ http://www.$2.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply but unable to solve the problem